# Calculating logistic regression coefficients by hand

Tags: r, logistic-regression, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to estimate logistic regression in R calculating everything by hand. 
I am able to create logit and loglikelihood function however I am not able to solve it using som non-linear solver

I would like to ask for advice

```
df <- read_csv("http://courses.atlas.illinois.edu/spring2016/STAT/STAT200/RProgramming/data/Default.csv")
df


df$default = ifelse(df$default == "Yes", 1, 0)

logit <- function(x, b0, b1) {
  1/(1 + exp(-b0 - b1*x))
}



Loglikel <- function(y, x, b0, b1) {
  b0 = rep(b0, length(y))
  b1 = rep(b1, length(y))
  p <- logit(x, b0, b1)
  sum(y*log(p)  + (1 - y)*log(1-  p))
}


Loglikel(df$default, df$balance, -10, 0.005)


library(stats4)

mle(Loglikel, 
    start = list(b0 = 0, b1 = 0), 
    fixed = list(y = df$default, x = df$balance))
```

Comment: This would be a better question if you provided more detail. What goes wrong? Do you get an error? (What error?) A bad result? (What is it, and how are you sure it is wrong?) Warnings? (What do they say?) It takes forever? (How long did you wait?)

Comment: A different way to go about this "by hand" is to construct the quadratic discriminant assuming the classes have equal variance (as estimated by pooled variance). This is just some matrix algebra, no iteration or search required. When the classes have different variances, the contours of posterior class probability are conic sections; when they are the same, contours are planes. I believe the  posterior class probability estimated that way is pretty much the same as a logistic regression; it might be appropriate to just use that, or at least you can use it as a check on a logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and modified it a little bit to pass parameters as a vector:

```
df <- read_csv("http://courses.atlas.illinois.edu/spring2016/STAT/STAT200/RProgramming/data/Default.csv")
df$default <- ifelse(df$student == "Yes", 1, 0)

logit <- function(x, b0, b1) {
  1/(1 + exp(-b0-b1*x))
}
Loglikel <- function(par, y, x){
  p <- logit(x, par[1], par[2])
  sum(y*log(p)  + (1-y)*log(1-p))
}
```

We are now ready to use a non-linear solver (e.g., `nlm`) to obtain estimates for parameters:

```
nlm_fit <- nlm(Loglikel, p = c(-2,0.001), x=df$balance, y=df$default)
```

which gives

```
> nlm_fit
...
$estimate
[1] -2.0002960 -0.2666521
...
```

`nlm` uses a Newton-Raphson-type solver to minimize the MLE. At the same time, `glm` uses the Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares algorithm, which means that output of `glm` and `nlm` does not have to agree:

```
glm_fit <- glm(default ~ balance, family = binomial(link="logit"), data = df)

> glm_fit

Call:  glm(formula = default ~ balance, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      balance  
 -1.7004224    0.0009409
```

Check this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178492/which-optimization-algorithm-is-used-in-glm-function-in-r) out, it gives a good summary of what is going on under the hood of `glm`.